# How to take in a list of numbers with negative signs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, negative-number

I tried this but it gave me this error: `SyntaxError: illegal expression for augmented assignment`.

The input will be something like this: `-2 4 -1`

```py
x_forces, y_forces, z_forces = 0
x_forces, y_forces, z_forces += map(int, input().split(' '))
```

Comment: You might want to give us the language you are using

Comment: I'm using python 3

Comment: What you want to do is just remove the `+=` and set it to an `=`

Comment: What should your output look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
x_forces, y_forces, z_forces = 0, 0, 0
n = [i for i in map(int, input().split(' '))]

x_forces += n[0]
y_forces += n[1]
z_forces += n[2]

print(x_forces, y_forces, z_forces)
```